# how to store filename to mysql by upload

Tags: php, mysql

this mycode 
I'am try to edit but no success.

---

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filUpload"]["tmp_name"],"docfile/".$_FILES["filUpload"]["name"]))
    {
        //*** Insert Record ***//
        $file = $_FILES["filUpload"]["name"];
        $fileup = mysql_real_escape_string($file);
        $strSQL = "INSERT INTO fileproject(filename)  VALUES($fileup);";
        if(!$strSQL){
            echo "<h1>Error Store FileName2DB<h1>";
            exit;
        }
        echo "Upload Complete<br>";
    }
```

Comment: you dont run your query. `$strSQL` is the query in a string, but you do nothing with is

Comment: $fileup is a string use quotes and use mysqli_query

Comment: chose the best answer and mark as accepted

Comment: This is a Typo and resolved in a manner unlikely to be of benefit to future readers.

Answer (score 3):

you dont execute your query. You have to use your object to the database for query.

```
  try
 {
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yourdb;charset=utf8', 'root', 'yourpassword',
    array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
 }
catch(Exception $e)
{
die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
}
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filUpload"]["tmp_name"],"docfile/".$_FILES["filUpload"]["name"]))
{
    //*** Insert Record ***//
    $file = $_FILES["filUpload"]["name"];
    $fileup = mysql_real_escape_string($file);
    $strSQL = "INSERT INTO fileproject(filename)  VALUES($fileup)";
    $result=$bdd->query($strSQL);
    if(!$strSQL){
        echo "<h1>Error Store FileName2DB<h1>";
        exit;
    }

    echo "Upload Complete<br>";
}
```

Comment: and `$bdd` comes from ?

Comment: Fileup is a string use quotes

Answer (score 0):

You are not using mysql extension for executing your query. Other example is about to `PDO`.

You can also `INSERT` the new row by using `mysqli_*` extension.

**MYSQL procedural structure:**

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filUpload"]["tmp_name"],"docfile/".$_FILES["filUpload"]["name"]))
 {
     //*** Insert Record ***//
     $file = $_FILES["filUpload"]["name"];
     $fileup = mysql_real_escape_string($file);
     $strSQL = "INSERT INTO fileproject (filename)  VALUES ('$fileup')";


     // here you need to use mysqli_* extension
     if(mysqli_query($conn, $strSQL)){
         echo  "Upload Complete<br>";
     }
     else{
         echo "<h1>Error Store FileName2DB<h1>";
         // exit;
     }
 }


mysqli_close($conn); // DATABASE CONNECTION CLOSE
?>
```

**Side note:**

As I mentioned in comments `$fileup` value is a string value so you need to use single quotes between the variable.